# Application Settings in Azure Portal not Overwriting Generic Values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service

This is my process for setting some connection strings in my Azure hosted app:

1. When debugging, the strings are stored in `Web.Config` as normal, and this is encrypted with `aspnet_regiis` to hide them in the version control.
2. At publish, these are set to some generic values in `Web.Release.Config`:

   ```
   <add xdt:Transform="Insert" name="SPsvcUsername" connectionString="username"/>
   <add xdt:Transform="Insert" name="SPsvcPassword" connectionString="password"/>
   ```
3. I then go into the App Service on the Azure portal and under Application Settings -> Connection Strings I add the actual values required, just using the same name, e.g. `SPsvcUsername`. This overwrites the generic values and everything is fine and dandy.

[image]

This has always worked since I started doing it and I have had 0 issues apart from ocasionally I would have to wait a couple of minutes for it to update.

However, today it just doesn't apply the settings that I input in Azure Portal.

When I go into the command prompt and call

```
more web.config
```

I can see that the connection string scontains the generic values `username` and `password`

What gives? Why did this suddenly stop working? Was there an update that addressed this that I haven't read about?

Any advice is much appreciated. Including anything on whether my original process actually makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are replaced at runtime, not in the file.

So when you access the connection string via:

```
string username = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SPsvcUsername"].ConnectionString;
```

It will have the value from the Application Settings blade.

Comment: But it doesn't seem to - I am getting a "incorrect username/password" error when I try using the values after publsih, but when I debug locally it works fine

Comment: Make sure you set the settings in the correct section of the application settings blade. App settings map to appSettings and Connection strings map to connectionStrings section. The name must also exactly match.

Comment: It's all set up correctly - as I mentioned I have been using this method for a few months now, and I haven't touched those settings at all - it just suddenly stopped working today and its driving me crazy!

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? But seriously, a restart can help.

Comment: juunas I've been doing some debugging and it actually looks like the right values are being passed, but for some reason authentication fails... How can SharePoint CSOM auth fail on the Azure but succeed locally... I am so lost

Comment: I opened a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404829/csom-authentication-succeeds-when-debugging-but-fails-on-azure-app-service) if you are interested

Comment: Yeah, I upvoted that one. Can't really help with that though, SharePoint is outside my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks juunas, but weirdly it doesn't seem like a SharePoint problem, as how can it be? The auth works perfectly and only fails after publish which makes me think its an Azure issue